# How to +1 a post in google plus using android app?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-one

We are developing an android app that requires to have a like functionality which should be +1 in Google Plus. We tried with the [Google developer site](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend) but it says of a url:

```
private static final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
// Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
mPlusOneButton.initialize(URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

The URL here refers to a link of a page or a web site or so. Now what we wish to have is to +1 a post. Is there any way we could do so?

Comment: here Url is the url of page which you want to +1. try using any playstore link and then see on that page.

Comment: I wish to add a +1 to a post on google plus. I wonder if we really get a url for the **google plus posts** ? Also we are currently posting on google plus using an intent so, it should be possible to retrieve either the url of the posy or the post id from the intent data.

Comment: I had the same problem recently and hacked a solution to this problem; you can contact me for further details!

Comment: Thanks @Eenvincible. I wish to knoow how you got through with this issue.

Comment: Actually I did manage to ask users to like a page (not a single post).  Let me know if you are interested in that part and I will explain to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, at least as of this posting, Like or +1 a post using the API: Here is the documentation:

[Google+ API Frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/faq)

Answer (score 0):

what type of post you're referring here? if in case we take this question [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779426/how-to-1-a-post-in-google-plus-using-android-app) put this URL in `mPlusOneButton.initialize(**URL HERE**, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);`

Comment: Actually, we have coded the portion of sharing a post to the user's gplus stream, now we are trying if we can +1 that post or for +1 do we really require that post to be there... or not??

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. Try this url.

```
private static final String URL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourPackageName";
```

you should also see the link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/app-activities

Comment: I wish not to like the app, instead like a post published in gplus.